# Как запустить сервер, помогите новичку

Tags: mysql, node.js

Помогите, я супер новичок, мне надо помощь, если в кратце:
я создал с помощью nodeJS приложение сервер, с подключением к базе данных, у меня на это ушло 2-3 недели, теперь я могу выводить данные с БД, и рендерить их на свою страничку, я зарегал на AWS (амазоновском) Windows сервак, установил туда ноду, и теперь у меня на нем удаленно через RDP запускается мой сервер по адресу http://localhost:3000/, как мне перенаправить все запросы с интернета теперь на мой этот Виндовс-АВС сервак?
Только по подробней пожалуйста, большенство кода я скопировал и подделал под себя.
Public IPv4 DNS - example.com
Public IPv4 address - 3.123.84.11
**

### Мой код:

**

```
let express = require('express')
let mysql =  require('mysql');


let conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : #############
    user     : #############
    password : '#############',
    database : '#############'
  });

let query="SELECT * #############";
let current_products = [];
function f() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        conn.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");
            conn.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    })
}

async function asyncCall() {
    current_products = await f();
    current_products = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(current_products)).splice(0,1)
    console.log(current_products);
}
asyncCall();

const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? 3000
const app = express()

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server hes been started on port ${PORT}...`);
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/index',(req,res)=>{
    res.json(current_products[0]);
})
```

### **КОД В index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let url="http://localhost:3000/index";
    fetch(url).then(response => response.json()
        .then( (result) => {
            let nameProd = document.querySelector('.products__name')
            nameProd.innerHTML =  `Назва: ${result.Column_2}`
            let imgProd = document.querySelector(".products__image")
            imgProd.innerHTML =  `<img src="${result.Column_15}"">`
                 
        }).catch(error => console.log('error:', error)))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, то надо было просто запускать свой app.js на 80 порту, перед этим его освободить